# How do I get a pattern of this kind?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Given N natural numbers and a number x, How do I find the number(s) **i** from set (1...N)
at which quotient of x divided by **i** is different from what at **i-1**?

*Example*:

I have x=10 and N=10 then values for each **i** belongs to N, {10 , 5 , 3 , 2 ,2 , 1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 }

**How it came?**

{10/1 , 10/2 ,10 /3 ,10/4 ,10 /5 , 10/6 ,10/7 ,10/8 ,10/8 , 10/9 , 10/10 }
so my quotients for 4 and 5 are same and for 6,7,8,9,10 are same ? So how do I find this numbers (4,5) and (6,7,8,9,10) without actually iterating over all 1....N  ?

Comment: Well, you may iterate over quotients.

Comment: please eloborate

Comment: At least All the number less than or equal to $\sqrt{x}$ fullfil your condition.

Comment: Umm...the floor function?  Not really sure what you're asking for here.  You can *define* a set without any iteration at all, unless you are trying to produce an *algorithm,* and then we would need a computing model.  Do you just want notation that is clearer?

Comment: I want algorithm @WildCard

Comment: @Ahmad Not that but x/2 I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pseudo-algorithm :

Given two number $N$ and $x$,
Output : a set of all numbers $i$ such that $\lfloor \frac{x}{i} \rfloor \not= \lfloor \frac{x}{i-1} \rfloor $

1) let $i=2$ till $\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$.

2) add to the list the number $\lceil \frac{x}{i} + \frac{1}{x} \rceil$.

3) add all numbers that are less or equal to $\lfloor \sqrt{x} \rfloor$.

4) remove from the list any number bigger than $N$.

5) output the list.

the running time for this algorithm is $O(\sqrt{x})$, which is very fast than iteration.

For example : $N=40$ and $x=105$

first $i=2$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 53$ we add $53$ to the list.

$i=3$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 36$ we add $36$ to the list.

$i=4$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 27$ we add $27$ to the list.

$i=5$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 22$ we add $22$ to the list.

$i=6$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 18$ we add $18$ to the list.

$i=7$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 16$ we add $16$ to the list.

$i=8$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 14$ we add $14$ to the list.

$i=9$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 12$ we add $12$ to the list.

$i=10$ so $\lceil \frac{105}{i} +\frac{1}{105} \rceil = 11$ we add $11$ to the list.

$i=11$ is bigger than $\lfloor \sqrt{105} \rfloor = 10$, so step $2$ is done.

in step $3$ we add the number $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$.

so the list is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,18,22,27,36,53 \}$

now in step $4$ and since $53 > N=40$ so we remove it from the list and output the final list which is :

$\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,14,16,18,22,27,36 \}$

hope you find what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks!@Ahmad nice explanation , and I see that maximum number of such numbers are 2*root(x)-1

Comment: you are welcome.

Comment: if N=x can we do better?

Comment: @ShubhamRajput i don't think so, but if $N < 2\sqrt{x}$ then we could make better so its $min(N, 2\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 0):

Stop dividing as soon as the quotient only decreases by 1.

You'll see 10, 5, 3, 2.

Your groups are 10 to 6 and 5 to 4.

Let's do it with 100:

100, 50, 33, 25, 20, 16, 14, 12, 11.

So the groups are, 100 to 51, 50 to 34, 33 to 26, etc.

This works because if a/b = c then a/c = b also.  In other words, it works because multiplication is commutative.